# How can I "import scipy.signal as signal" and still use python sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, scipy, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to use Sphinx to automatically generate documentation for a python project. One of the modules requires the scipy.signal package, which I try to import using the following: import scipy.signal as signal. Although the code runs just fine, making html with Sphinx results in a segmentation fault (output below). I can, however, use "import scipy as sp", making sure to put scipy directory in my sys.path and the documentation is generated without any problems, but of course, then I won't have the functionality in my code that I need.

I made a very simple test case to demonstrate the problem, creating a testclass with a few docstrings. I am inluding it below along with my .rst's. Commenting out the line "import scipy.signal as signal", everything works quite well.

Thanks for any insights into how to avoid seg faulting while still importing scipy.signal.
Lauren

### Sphinx output:

```
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.0.5
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
make: *** [html] Segmentation faults
```

### pyexample.py

```
import scipy.signal as signal

class TestClass:
    """The TestClass class is used to lalala. I would like this docstring to be     documented by sphinx.
    """

    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B

    # Style to use for printing
    def __str__(self):
        str =  "A = " + self.A.__str__() + "\n\n"
        str += "B = " + self.B.__str__() + "\n\n"
        return str

    def __add__(self):
        """Add A+B."""
        total = self.A+self.B
        return total

    def addx(self,x):
        """Add A+x."""
        total = self.A+x
        return total
```

### index.rst

```
.. Test documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Sun Jan  2 20:34:04 2011.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Test's documentation!
================================

Contents:

.. toctree::

   docstrings

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

### docstrings.rst

```
My Modules and Functions
************************************
Here are some modules.

The pyexample Module
======================
.. automodule:: pyexample

.. autoclass:: pyexample.TestClass
   :members:
```

Comment: If you have conflicting names somewhere in your pipeline you have to avoid naming the packages as the same. Your code should be able to handle that you import `scipy.signal as sp` and then use that instead and it wouldn't reduce readability. Also You do not use signal in your example, so it should not be required to be there?